# como remplazar el stubbing previo de mockito

Tags: java, mockito, cucumber

Recientemente pensé en modificar mi API para probar mi aplicación de escritorio para que además de escribir los escenarios de prueba en código pudiera hacerlo en archivos [gherkin](/questions/tagged/gherkin).

Mi problema viene causado por el uso de muchos pasos con órden impredecibe y su interacción con mocks, pues al parecer o no toma mi mock o se queda con el valor anterior.

## Código

### Definición de pasos

```
public class StepDefinition {

    private LoginUsersService usersService;

    private FontFactory fontFactory;

    private NavigationHandler navigationHandler;

    private LoginWindow loginWindow;

    public StepDefinition() {
        usersService = mock(LoginUsersService.class);
        navigationHandler = mock(NavigationHandler.class);
        fontFactory = mock(FontFactory.class);
        when(
                fontFactory
                        .getFont(
                                Matchers.anyString()
                        )
        ).thenReturn(
                new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 24)
        );
        loginWindow = new LoginWindow(navigationHandler, usersService, fontFactory);
    }

    @Given("^I write login credentials using user \\'([A-Za-z]+)\\' and password \\'([A-Za-z]+)\\'$")
    public void writeLoginFields(String nickName, String password){
        loginWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        loginWindow.setVisible(true);

        loginWindowPageObject = new LoginWindowPageObject();
        loginWindowPageObject.setUserFieldContent(nickName);
        loginWindowPageObject.setPasswordFieldContent(password);
    }

    @And("^I click Login with wrong credentials$")
    public void clickLoginButtonWithWrongCredentials(){
        reset(usersService);
        when(usersService.authenticate(Matchers.any(LoginUser.class)))
                .thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
        loginWindowPageObject.clickAccept();
    }

    @And("^I click Login with correct credentials$")
    public void clickLoginButtonWithCorrectCredentials(){
        reset(usersService);
        when(usersService.authenticate(Matchers.any(LoginUser.class)))
                .thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                loginWindow.setVisible(false);
                menu.setVisible(true);
                return null;
            }
        }).when(navigationHandler).goToMenu(Matchers.any(JFrame.class));
        loginWindowPageObject.clickAcceptAndWait();
        menuPageObject = new MainMenuPageObject();
    }

.
.
.
}
```

### PageObject

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.ContainerOperator;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JButtonOperator;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JDialogOperator;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JFrameOperator;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JLabelOperator;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JPasswordFieldOperator;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JTextFieldOperator;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LoginWindowPageObject {
    private JTextFieldOperator userField;
    private JPasswordFieldOperator passwordField;
    private JButtonOperator btnAccept;
    private JButtonOperator btnClear;
    private JDialogOperator userNotFoundMessage;
    private ResourceBundle bundle;
    private JLabelOperator dialogMessage;

public LoginWindowPageObject() {
    bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("inventarios/gui/desktop/Bundle"); // NOI18N
    ContainerOperator containerFrame = new JFrameOperator(bundle.getString("LoginWindow.title")); // NOI18N
    userField = new JTextFieldOperator(containerFrame);
    passwordField = new JPasswordFieldOperator(containerFrame);
    btnAccept = new JButtonOperator(containerFrame, 0);
    btnClear = new JButtonOperator(containerFrame, 1);
}

public String getUserFieldContent() {
    return userField.getText();
}

public void setUserFieldContent(String user) {
    userField.setText(user);
}

public String getPasswordFieldContent() {
    return passwordField.getText();
}

public void setPasswordFieldContent(String password) {
    passwordField.setText(password);
}

public void clickAccept() {
    btnAccept.pushNoBlock();
}

public void clickAcceptAndWait() {
    btnAccept.clickMouse();
}

public void clickClear() {
    btnClear.clickMouse();
}

public void userNotFoundIsShown() {
    userNotFoundMessage = new JDialogOperator("Credenciales incorrectas");
    Assert.assertNotNull(userNotFoundMessage);
    dialogMessage = new JLabelOperator(userNotFoundMessage);
    Assert.assertEquals("Usuario " + userField.getText() + " no encontrado", dialogMessage.getText());
    JButtonOperator jbo = new JButtonOperator(userNotFoundMessage);
    jbo.push();
    userNotFoundMessage = null;
}

public JLabelOperator getDialogMessage() {
    return dialogMessage;
}
}
```

### feature de ejemplo

```
#----------------------------------
# Navigation trough the windows of the application
#----------------------------------

Feature: Window Navigation

   Scenario: Tour trough the client fails for unauthorized user
      As a non authorized used I should not be able to navigate
      Given I write login credentials using user 'wrong' and password 'wrong'
      And I click Login with wrong credentials
      Then error prompt should appear

   Scenario: Tour trough the application should be possible for authorized user
      Given I write login credentials using user 'wrong' and password 'wrong'
      And I click the clear fields button
      Then Login window fields should be empty
      Given I write login credentials using user 'correct' and password 'correct'
      And I click Login with correct credentials
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví, resulta que mockito tiene una anotación similar a JUnit y TestNG para hacer cosas cada que termina un escenario, se les conoce como hooks.

Les dejo un tutorial [acá](https://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/).

Y un fragmento del código de mi solución:

```
@Before
public void beforeScenario(){
    usersService = mock(LoginUsersService.class);
    navigationHandler = mock(NavigationHandler.class);
    fontFactory = mock(FontFactory.class);
    when(
            fontFactory
                    .getFont(
                            Matchers.anyString()
                    )
    ).thenReturn(
            new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 24)
    );
    loginWindow = new LoginWindow(navigationHandler, usersService, fontFactory);
    menu = new Menu(navigationHandler);
    inventoryManagement = new InventoryManagement(navigationHandler, productService, validatorFactory);
}

@After
public void afterScenario(){
    reset(usersService);
    loginWindow.dispose();
}
```